# React native: Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode or parent without a measure function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I checked all of my code for any syntax errors and I can't find anything. I tried everything I found online and similar questions asked here and nothing worked, which is why I'm posting a new question.

This is the exact error I'm getting:

`Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! (Trying to add a 'RCTRawText [text: 0]' to a 'RCTView')`

I read somewhere that [text: someything] can be used as a hint to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Share some code.

Comment: Can you please share your code? so that it will be easy to analyze the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was this

```html
<View>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>s
</View>
```

Having text outside of `Text` gives an error on Android but not on iOS. I find it weird that it's picked up only on one platform when it should give a warning or an error on both.

Comment: Was that actually the code that caused the issue? It seems like from the error message the extra text should be a string containing "0" not containing "s"

Comment: i wasted like 1 hour on this, even the log is not helpful at all. they should make error log more verbose i guess

Comment: @qwwqwwq its not the actual code, it's an example. It doesn't matter if its 0 or s, the point is that having text outside of <Text> produces that error in Android

Comment: @AbhishekGarg I agree! I spent hours reading the code carefully trying to find out what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Placing Text elements on same incline row might also trigger such error e.g like

```
<View><Text>My Text</Text></View><View><Text>Another Text</Text></View>
```

instead of

```
<View>
 <Text>My Text</Text>
</View>
<View>
 <Text>Another Text</Text>
</View>
```

It will be battered if you place the code here too